# <center> tag centered everything in Outlook Web App, the text couldn't align left

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, center, outlook-web-app

**I just want an email in the center but the text align left, the code works well everywhere but doesn't work in Outlook Web App.  We use outlook windows client to send out the email, which overwrite the code, so when OWA receive the email, all text align center.**

People say the

> `<center>`

tag is what is required by Outlook and outlook.com.

When I deleted the `table align="center"` and the tag, OWA works fine, but the email won't be in the center in outlook email client.
**Even if delete the `<center>` tag and just keep `table align="center"` for making the email centered in the outlook email client, the text sill doesn't align left in OWA. Please help me. Thanks in advance!**
**Also tried to put text into a `<p>` or `<span>` or `<div>` with align left, still won't work**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center style="width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" style="width: 680px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;">
            <tr>
            <td align="left !important">
            <![endif]-->

            <table align="left !important" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#33ffff" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; clear: both; border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align: left !important;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left !important" height="24" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; Margin: 0;text-align: left !important;">This text couldn't align left in Outlook Web App!
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
             <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought `<center>` was deprecated.

Comment: @Yaakov Ainspan Thank you for your reply. But even if delete the <center> tag and just keep table align="center" for making the email centered in the outlook email client, the text sill doesn't align left in OWA.

Comment: `<td align="left !important">` is not a valid tag. Try `<td align="left">`. `<center>` is not deprecated for email.

Comment: @gwally Thank you so much for you reply. I tried <td align="left"> first, didn't work. So I added !important to all of them... still not working :(

Comment: @RanTian Adding `!important` is never going to work for `<td align="left">` because it's not a css value, it's a table tag. I tested your html code in Litmus in a wide variety of Outlook clients and it always aligns left.

Comment: Hey @gwally Thank you so much for testing for me. Really appreciate it! I tested earlier. It works well if use Litmus to send and Outlook Web App to receive. But in reality, we use outlook windows client to send out the email, which overwrite the code, so when OWA receive the email, all text align center. If I delete <center> tag and <!--[if mso]><table align="center"... It solved the issue. But the entire email won't be in the center. Sorry I didn't make this scenario clear.